# jQuery accordion issues/tips

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've got a jQuery accordion (not using the actual .accordion function mind you - as this is a bit more complex) that isn't operating properly.  Basically when you have click on one menu and it opens, then click on another, the previous menu should close - but mine doesn't and I can't figure out why.

Can someone check my code to see what I'm missing?

Also, since I have your attention, is there a way for me to set up the jQuery so that the bottom menu option (in this case the contact section) slides down revealing the content *above* it, instead of below it?

HTML

```
    <div id="container">
            <div class="menu">
                <section id="about-me">
                    <a href="#" id="about" class="nav">about</a>
                        <div class="menu-stuffing">
(info)
                        </div>
                </section>
                <section id="my-work">
                    <a href="#" id="portfolio" class="nav">work</a>
                </section>
                <section id="my-blog">
                    <a href="" id="blog" class="nav">blog</a>
                </section>
                <section id="contact-form">
                    <a href="#" id="kit" class="nav">contact</a>
                    <div class="menu-stuffing" id="contact-form">
(info)
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
        $("div.menu-stuffing").hide();
        $('div.menu > section > a > div').hide();
        $('div.menu > section > a').click(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast')
            .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div.menu-stuffing").hide();
$('div.menu > section > a > div').hide();

$('div.menu > section > a').click(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast')
  .parent().siblings().find('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/t8j5F/1/)

The problem is that you were searching the `siblings` inside the `section` where you clicked `a` and not in the other `section siblings`